# Short term CPU scheduling on heterogeneous architectures

Tags: cpu

**Firstly, I'd like to mention I wasn't sure where this question should go. It may be better of in a sister site but I didn't know which one therefore if it is in the wrong category, would someone be able to migrate it?**

I'm conducting some research into how heterogeneous architectures work in terms of the short term scheduling queue. I know its a collection of different processors such as CPU's and GPU's.

I also found out some information regarding asymmetric scheduling. I know homogeneous uses symmetrical, but struggling to understand how heterogeneous works?

Comment: This is probably going to be much too broad, unfortunately; you're basically asking for a lecture on how heterogenous processors work. If you can reword your question to be more specific, that would greatly increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: @RileyAvron Sorry, question was kind of confusing that I had ask. If I said does heterogeneous use asymmetric scheduling would that help? That way I know Im on the right course